# Hiberate Envers and threads

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, hibernate-envers

I want to know, is it possibile to force Hibernate to call my custom RevisionListener in the same thread as the user session thread? (GWT) 
I need such behaviour to store in revisions name of user, who is making the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hibernate and envers engine run on the thread which boots up the framework and there is no way to delegate the execution of the listeners to other threads.

The information your listener needs should be passed or provided at invocation time and your listener could use a `ThreadLocal` to lookup the value and use it much like how spring security based applications get this information in the revision listeners via `SpringSecurityContextHolder`.

Comment: I think I don't understand - if envers are run on some specific thread, wouldn't ThreadLocal return always the same object?

Comment: @mnowak Envers runs on the same thread as hibernate.  If that thread where you are doing your session operations does not have access to whatever context you need, you need to pass it or make it available.  That's a threading model issue with your GWT application, not hibernate.